# Pattern or convention to create a file and return enum as result

Tags: java, design-patterns, convention

**SCENARIO**
I've a util class that makes a zip file from folder, and returns the file. This works perfect.

```
public static class MakeZip {
    // returns zip file, null otherwise
    public static File doZip(File folderToZip)
}
```

**PROBLEM**
 came when I want to control the possible error scenarios, connection problems, empty folder, zip fail etc... I'm wondering best way to create the file and return the result, for this, I created an enum

```
public static enum ZIP_RESULT {
    OK, KO, EMPTY_FOLDER;
}
```

**IDEAS**
**a)** Create a file class attribute

```
private File zipFile;
```

and return `ZIP_FILE` enum in doZip method.

```
public ZIP_RESULT doZip(File folderToZip)
```

**b)** Modify the `File` sent:

```
public ZIP_RESULT doZip(File folderToZip, File fileToZip)
```

**c)** ????

**QUESTION**
There is a pattern, convention or best practice for this kind of file modification expecting enum as result? I guess is a really typical scenario to have it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throw an Exception. You can extend `Exception` or implement `Throwable`.

The third bullet for when to use an exception describes your situation as described [here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html):

> Exceptions due to resource failures: Exceptions that get generated
>   when resources fail. For example: the system runs out of memory or a
>   network connection fails. The client's response to resource failures
>   is context-driven. The client can retry the operation after some time
>   or just log the resource failure and bring the application to a halt.

Comment: This, I would say is the convention.  
If need be, you could create your own Exception that expects your Enum to be provided in the Constructor

`public MyException (Zip_Error_Enum  val)() {}`

Answer (score 0):

this is what I would do,

instead of this :

```
public static File doZip(File folderToZip)
```

and have something like this instead

```
public static Map.Entry<File,ZIP_RESULT>  doZip(File folderToZip)
```

so you'll have both the data in `Entry` and you can use them as appropriate.